# Slide Orientation (Vertical-Portrait Vs. Horizontal)) using PHPPowerPoint

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phppowerpoint

I'm using PHPPowerPoint which makes the powerpoint amazingly; the problem is I want the layout of the page to be vertical instead of Horizontal. Does anyone know how I can set this property! 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Found this solution to your question.

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/workitem/1832

Your question is quite old but can be of help to someone who stumbles upon this post.

Comment: You should consider quoting the relevant portions of that website so that the answer is available on SO even if the page you link to eventually moves or goes away

Comment: @StormeHawke There's a patch on the website actually which is useful it's not a tutorial.